# Incorrect results for Hive Count

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I am getting incorrect counts when doing full count of the table compared to when where clause is being used. Results shown below:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM Table_MAS MAS;
OK
11317322

hive> SELECT count(1) FROM Table_MAS where Col_A IS NOT NULL and Col_B is NOT NULL;
OK
552589106
```

I have already performed Analyze of the table and repair. Doesnt look like there is anything wrong.

Wanted to see if anyone else has faced a similar situation and if so how did you correct it?

I have already performed Analyze of the table and repair.

Obviously I expected the count with where clause to be always equal or lower than full count.

Answer (score 1):

you should use:

```
 select count(*) FROM Table_MAS MAS;
```

COUNT(*) will count the number of rows, while COUNT(1) will count non-null values in expression and COUNT(column) will count all non-null values in column.